# Load a specific iframe using jQuery onClick function

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am trying to load a specific iframe (Youtube video) depending on what  is clicked.

```
<a href="#" class="video"></a>
<a href="#" class="video"></a>
<div class="video-wrapper">
    <iframe src="" id="youtube"></iframe>
</div>
```

My incomplete JQuery is as such;

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.video').click(function() {
   var videoSelect = $(this).attr('href');

  $("#youtube-video").attr
  });
});
</script>
```

Any help welcome. Thanks

Comment: You have a syntax error, attr on "you-tube"-element

Answer (score 5):

**HTML :** *(just ID gonna be easier)*

```
<a href="JDglMK9sgIQ" class="video">#1</a>
<a href="LpKyzSxVhk4" class="video">#2</a>

<div class="video-wrapper">
    <iframe id="youtube" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$('a.video').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    var src = '//www.youtube.com/embed/'+id;
    $("#youtube").attr('src', src);
    return false;
});
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/tdLnoxmo/

---

**More better *(using data attr)***

**HTML :**

```
<a href="#" class="video" data-youtube="JDglMK9sgIQ">#1</a>
<a href="#" class="video" data-youtube="LpKyzSxVhk4">#2</a>

<div class="video-wrapper"></div>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$('[data-youtube]').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-youtube');
    var src = '//www.youtube.com/embed/'+id;
    var iframe = '<iframe id="youtube" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" src="'+src+'" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    $(".video-wrapper").html(iframe);
    return false;
});
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/l2aelba/tdLnoxmo/75/

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to autoplay the videos (below). Any idea how to add an anchor to each link? So... on a long list of YT links, you click a link near the bottom of the page, anchor to the iframe at the top of the page, and autoplay the video? Here's the autoplay bit (+'?autoplay=1'):

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('a.video').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    var src = '//www.youtube.com/embed/'+id+'?autoplay=1';
    $("#youtube").attr('src', src);
    return false;
```